# Image processing with ionic1 (apk) versus Chrome (debugger) using ocrad.js

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework, ocr

I've developed an application which captures the image and processes it to extract some data.
Here is the image:

[image]

When I'm running the code in Chrome debugger, I clearly receive the desired text

> Lot # 170814

[image]

But when I'm running the **same** code as Android application, I receive some gibberish.
[image]

Common functions:

```
function OCRImage(image) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
  canvas.width = image.naturalWidth;
  canvas.height = image.naturalHeight;
  canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0)
  return OCRAD(canvas)
}

function OCRPath(url, callback) {
  var image = new Image()
  image.src = url;
  image.onload = function () {
    callback(OCRImage(image))
  }
}
```

JS code for Chrome:

```
 OCRPath('img.png', function (words) {
    alert(words)
  })
```

JS code for Android:

```
  var options = {
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
    mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    allowEdit: true,
    correctOrientation: true
  }      
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options)
        .then(
          function (imageURI) {
            OCRPath('img.png',
              function (words) {
                alert(words)
              })},
              function (err) {
                alert('Error');
              });
      }
```

What can be the difference? It's literally the same image and same image processing code. Any suggestions? May be, any other way to make OCR?

Comment: shouldn't it be `return OCRAD(canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height));`?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey , I took this code snipped from the library downloaded by npm (okrabyte package at node_modules\ocrad.js\examples\url.html).

Answer (score 1):

> literally the same image and same image processing code

It isn't - in the web you're loading `'img.png'` into an `<img>`, then on load copying that into a `<canvas>` that you then pass to `OCRAD`.

On Android you're calling `$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options)` first to get a promise that resolves with `imageURI` once the user has selected an image.

Once you have that you ignore `imageURI` and load `'img.png'` directly instead.

The results have accessed the image, but may have a scaled or otherwise lower resolution version - for instance `Lot # 170814` becomes `_l # 1 TO81`, but `FISSURE DIAMOND` seems to be found in the larger title text ok.

Possible solutions:

Switch to base-64 encoded image using `destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL`

```
var options = {
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
    mediaType: Camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    allowEdit: true,
    correctOrientation: true
}      
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options)
    .then(
         function (imageURI) {
             OCRPath(imageURI, alert, alert);
         });
```

Alternatively you shouldn't need the slightly roundabout approach to load the `<img>` then put that into a `<canvas>` - the only reason you're doing that is to get the bytes of the image to `OCRAD`. It's the best way to do that on the web, but on Android you already have the file - you should be able to pass it directly to `OCRAD`.